# Novel or short story. A planet is settled by Irish Catholics. Snakes are important part of ecosystem here. Change StPatrick and snakes story

Tags: story-identification, religion, planets

The story is set sometime after the planet has been settled. The settlers found snakes to be important to the ecosystem. Also directly important for the well-being of humans on the planet as they eat rats or the equivalent.

The people living on the planet change the story about St Patrick driving all the snakes out of Ireland. In their version of the story, St Patrick is driving the snakes to their planet.

An important visitor from Earth arrives believing there are no snakes on the planet and that this is important. I do not recall exactly what happens next. I remember the people on the planet trying to hide the existence of their snakes from him.

I read it about 2010 but I suspect it was written some decades earlier.

Comment: [St Patrick driving the snakes out of Ireland](https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/600c4409f694483df73bbf66/1618843606009-6QHW5ZDO6D1ZRQ6FCZ7U/StPaddyDrivesSnakesColor2.jpg?content-type=image%2Fjpeg)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"[Attention Saint Patrick](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/12072149)" by Murray Leinster ([ISFDB entry](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55577)), first published in 1960

[image: Image for "Attention Saint Patrick"]

From [this review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/4510153646):

> On the planet Eire, metal-eating creatures called dinies have all but destroyed homes, tools, and farm equipment, but the chairman overseeing the colony from Earth, Sean O'Donohue, won't have it. The colony's inadequate progress must be due to its worthless, lazy inhabitants and, you guessed it, their shenanigans!
>
> Just wait until he learns about the snakes that the colonists use to keep the dinies under control. You know, the snakes that Saint Patrick drove out of Ireland back on Earth. On Eire, it was another Patrick who brought the snakes to the grateful colonists, but don't tell that to O'Donohue.

Found with a search for `science fiction "planet" snakes "st patrick"`

[Available on Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/23439/pg23439-images.html).

> "This world should be ready!" snapped Sean O'Donohue accusingly. "It should be waitin' for the Caseys and Bradys and Fitzpatricks and other fine Erse people to move to and thrive on while the rest of the galaxy goes to pot with its new-fangled notions. That's the reason for this world's very existence. What set aside Erin on Earth, where our ancestors lived an' where their descendants are breathin' down each other's necks because there's so many of them? There was no snakes there! St. Patrick drove them out. What sets this world apart from all the other livable planets men have put down their smelly spaceships on? There's no snakes here! St. Patrick has great influence up in Heaven. He knew his fine Erse people would presently need more room than there was on Earth for them. So he'd a world set aside, and marked by the sign that no least trace of a serpent could exist on it. No creature like the one that blarneyed Mother Eve could be here! No——"
>
> "Our trouble's been dinies," began the president apologetically.
>
> But he froze. Something dark and sinuous and complacent oozed around the corner of the presidential mansion. The president of Eire sweated. He recognized the dark object. He'd believed it safely put away in pleasant confinement until the Dail Committee went away. But it wasn't. It was Timothy, the amiable six-foot black snake who faithfully and cordially did his best to keep the presidential mansion from falling down. Without him innumerable mouse-sized holes, gnawed by mouse-sized dinies, would assuredly have brought about its collapse. The president was grateful, but he'd meant to keep Timothy out of sight. Timothy must have escaped and as a faithful snake, loyal to his duty, he'd wriggled straight back to the presidential mansion.
>
> Like all Eire, he undoubtedly knew of the pious tradition that St. Patrick had brought the snakes to Eire, and he wasn't one to let St. Patrick down. So he'd returned and doubtless patrolled all the diny tunnels in the sagging structure. He'd cleaned out any miniature, dinosaurlike creatures who might be planning to eat some more nails. He now prepared to nap, with a clear conscience. But if Sean O'Donohue saw him—!